Comparing the definitions of Derivative in Guillemin Pollack and in other differential topology books.
In standard differential geometry and topology books I have seen the authors defining the derivative/differential in the following way:
Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map between two smooth manifolds.Then the differential of $f$ at $x\in M$ is defined to be the (linear) map $df_x:T_xM\to T_{f(x)}N$ which sends: $T_x(M)\ni v\longmapsto (df_x(v):C^\infty(N)\to \mathbb R ) \text{,i.e. $df_x(v)$ linear functional on } C^\infty(N)$ satisfying,
$df_x(v)(g)=v(g\circ f)$.
This definition does not require or involve any reference to local coordinates.
However,in Differential Topology by Guillemin,Pollack the way they have defined the differential of a smooth map at a point,is a bit different and I think an interesting one also.I am attempting to give the definition verbatim below:
Let $f:X\to Y$ be a smooth map between two arbitrary manifolds and let $x\in X$.We want the derivative of $f$ at $x$,to be a linear map between the tangent spaces $df_x:T_x(X)\to T_{f(x)}(Y)$.Naturally this generalized definition should be such that for maps between Euclidean spaces,the derivative would be the same as the usual one.Secondly,we demand the chain rule.
We can easily observe that there can be only one possible definition meeting these requisites.
Suppose $\phi:U(\subset \mathbb R^k)\to X$ is a local pararmetrization of $\phi(U)\subset X$ and $\psi:V(\subset \mathbb R^)\to Y$ be a local parametrization of $\psi(V)\subset Y$ and the parametrizations are such that $\phi(0)=x$ and $\psi(0)=f(x)$.If $U$ is small enough then we can draw a commutative diagram:
$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>f>>Y\\
@A \phi AA=@AA \psi A\\
U @>>h=\psi^{-1}\circ f\circ \phi >V\end{CD}$
We know what  $d\phi_0,d\psi_0$ and $dh_0$ must be and hence by the chain rule in hand,taking differentials on both sides converts the preceding diagram into a commutative square of linear tranformations.
$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
T_x X @>df_x>>T_{f(x)}Y\\
@A d\phi_0 AA=@AA d\psi_0 A\\
\mathbb R^k @>>dh_0> \mathbb R^l\end{CD}$
That is,we have the equality $df_x\circ d\phi_0=d\psi_0\circ dh_0$
As $d\phi_0$ is an isomorphism,there is only one acceptable definition for $df_x$ namely,
$df_x=d\psi_0\circ dh_0\circ d\phi_0^{-1}$
And then it is left to the reader to check that this definition of $df_x$ is independent of the choice of parametrizations $\phi$ and $\psi$.
My comment: I think they have,a priori,taken the assumption that any manifold $X$ can be embedded(looked as a submanifold) inside some $\mathbb R^N$ ,for $N$ sufficiently large,which allows one to assume without loss of generality that every smooth manifold $X$ is a submanifold of some ambient Euclidean space $\mathbb R^N$ and proceed in this way.
Nevertheless,the assumption that they have made is justified by Whitney's Embedding Theorem
Anyway as far as I think that these two definitions are equivalent provided that Whitney's proof of Embedding does not use the equivalence of these definitions somewhere in its proof.
So either way is fine.In case I am making subtle mistakes,please feel free to correct me at that point.

I don't see how this definition requires any embedding. Differential is defined locally, and local properties can be defined using maps - no need to embed whole manifold anywhere. Also, what is the question here?

Note that for $C^k$  manifolds with $0<k<\infty$ this is the only possible approach.

@Esgeriath You did not understand my point.We are using the fact that we know the meaning of all the other $3$ maps whose composition gives $df_x$.Now we know them only because Guillemin Pollack has defined them(particularly for manifolds $X$ embedded in $\mathbb R^N$.Otherwise the symbols $d\phi_0$ and $d\psi_0$ are also something that we do not know.But,because we are talking about embedded manifold in some $\mathbb R^N$,assumed at the beginning,so we know that $T_x(X)\subset T_x\mathbb R^N$ which can be identified with $\mathbb R^N$ and $d\phi_0$ makes sense.

You are correct. Guillemin & Pollack assume from the outset that their manifolds are embedded in $\Bbb R^N$ for some $N$. Then the point of their proof of Whitney embedding is to get the $N$ down to $2k+1$. You're right that this assumption leads to understanding the derivative of the parametrization map as a linear map between Euclidean spaces.

@TedShifrin Yes,I got it.Also I am big fan of your online lectures,Sir.I feel so nice that you replied in my comments...

@KishalaySarkar sorry for my confusion, I didn't read Guillemin Pollack. But I've read some other book in which differential was defined as this composition, with differentials of charts defined separately without any embedding (they were a part of definition of linear structure of $T_p M$). So that's possible as well.

@Esgeriath Be very careful. If you have an abstract manifold (i.e., one that is not equipped with any embedding in Euclidean space), the linear mapping $d\phi_0$ in the diagram above is not defined. Your "differential is defined locally" is just wrong. You must equip the topological space with more structure, i.e., equivalence of local homeomorphisms given by smoothness of the overlap maps on open subsets of Euclidean space.

You can easily formulate GP's definition without an embedding. All you need is a definition of $T_xX$ that does not use an embedding, and a definition of $d\phi$ for all coordinate charts $\phi$. You can do it by defining $T_xX$ as equivalence classes of coordinate chart vector pairs $(\phi, v)$, via the equivalence relation $(\phi, v) \sim (\psi, w)$ iff $D(\psi^{-1} \circ \phi)(\phi^{-1}(x))v = w$. Then  use notation $(\phi, v) = d\phi_{\phi^{-1}(x)}v$.

Since it seems most commenters don’t know Guillemin & Pollack’s book or its pedagogical aims, it’s a book intended for undergraduates and they purposely chose to work only with submanifolds to avoid abstract technicalities. The payoff is a beautiful concrete book with many deep results (e.g., Jordan-Brouwer separation, Borsuk-Ulam).
